# Display default image if the image isn't set

Tags: theming, media

**Case**

- A custom image field has been added to the `user entity`, this field contains a default image for users, which should display if an user doesn't add an image. This field is used on multiple templates across the site.

**Problem**

- Only at the user's profile page is the default image displaying when the image is not set (if set will show the image).
- Node templates and other entities will not display the default image. I tried to display the field with `theme_image()` with no success.

**Question**

- Why won't it display the default image?

When I dump the information about the fields attached to the current user, the field_picture is an empty array if the user has no image set. When the user does have an image set it will return [this](http://pastebin.com/zc6WUetJ)

**Setup**

- Field name: `field_picture`
- Field type: picture
- Field module: default image field module.

Comment: I have had frequent issues with default images

Comment: This comment on d.o seems to answer your query: https://www.drupal.org/node/740712#comment-8582941

Answer (score 0):

try: make sure in the field settings you have set BOTH default images.  There is one specific to that instance of the field, and one everywhere else it is used. The second is further down the screen:

IMAGE FIELD SETTINGS

These settings apply to the Image field everywhere it is used.